# Overwrite a nested list element using jsonnet

Tags: json, kubernetes, prometheus, jsonnet

**I have the following json**

```
{
    "namespace": "monitoring",
    "name": "alok",
    "spec": {
        "replicas": 1,
        "template": {
            "metadata": "aaa",
            "spec": {
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "image": "practodev/test:test",
                        "env": [
                            {
                                "name":"GF_SERVER_HTTP_PORT",
                                "value":"3000"
                            },
                            {
                                "name":"GF_SERVER_HTTPS_PORT",
                                "value":"443"
                            },
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**How do I add `deployment_env.json` using jsonnet?**

```
{
    "env": [
        {
            "name":"GF_AUTH_DISABLE_LOGIN_FORM",
            "value":"false"
        },
        {
            "name":"GF_AUTH_BASIC_ENABLED",
            "value":"false"
        },

    ]
}
```

I need to add it under spec.template.containers[0].env = deployment_env.json

I wrote the below jsonnet to do that. It appends a new element. But i need to change the existing 0th container element in the json. **Please suggest how to do it.**

```
local grafana_envs = (import 'custom_grafana/deployment_env.json');
local grafanaDeployment = (import 'nested.json') + {
    spec+: {
        template+: {
            spec+: {
                containers+: [{
                    envs: grafana_envs.env,
                }]
            }
        }
    },
};
grafanaDeployment
```

Answer (score 4):

See below for an implementation that allows adding `env` to an existing container by its index in the `containers[]` array.

Do note that `jsonnet` is much better suited to work with objects (i.e. dictionaries / maps) rather than arrays, thus it needs contrived handling via `std.mapWithIndex()`, to be able to modify an entry from its matching index.

```
local grafana_envs = (import 'deployment_env.json');

// Add extra_env to a container by its idx passed containers array
local override_env(containers, idx, extra_env) = (
  local f(i, x) = (
    if i == idx then x {env+: extra_env} else x
  );
  std.mapWithIndex(f, containers)
);
local grafanaDeployment = (import 'nested.json') + {
    spec+: {
        template+: {
            spec+: {
                containers: override_env(super.containers, 0, grafana_envs.env)
            }
        }
    },
};
grafanaDeployment
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternative implementation, not relying on the array index position, but `image` value instead (which makes more sense here as the `env` must be understood by the image implementation)

```
local grafana_envs = (import 'deployment_env.json');

local TARGET_CONTAINER_IMAGE = 'practodev/test:test';

local grafanaDeployment = (import 'nested.json') + {
  spec+: {
    template+: {
      spec+: {
        containers: [
          // TARGET_CONTAINER_IMAGE identifies which container to modify
          if x.image == TARGET_CONTAINER_IMAGE
          then x { env+: grafana_envs.env }
          else x
          for x in super.containers
        ],
      },
    },
  },
};
grafanaDeployment
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `std.mapWithIndex` is to explicitly iterate through the indexes based on the size of the list.

```
local grafana_envs = (import 'deployment_env.json');

local grafanaDeployment = (import 'nested.json') + {
    spec+: {
        template+: {
            spec+: {
                containers: 
                    [super.containers[0] { env+: grafana_envs.env }] 
                    + 
                    [
                      super.containers[i] 
                      for i in std.range(1, std.length(super.containers) - 1)
                    ]
            }
        }
    },
};
grafanaDeployment
```

If one needed to modify a specific index other than 0, say 5, then they could do so by putting an `if i == 5` in the loop.